# Database not found error in Apache Derby

Tags: java, netbeans, jdbc, derby, javadb

First, this is my first time with Apache Derby. I am using netbeans, willing to use embedded apache derby, and I followed the following tutorial for configuring and installing the database

http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/ide/java-db.html#starting

The attached image will show my database status in netbeans
[image]

My database name is "contact". Table name is "FRIENDS".

Following is my test code

**DatabaseConnector.java**

```
import java.sql.*;

public class DataBaseConnector
{
    private Connection con;

    public DataBaseConnector()
    {

    }

    private void createConnection()
    {
        try
        {
            Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver");
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby:contact","yohan","xyz");
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void closeConnection()
    {
        try
        {
            con.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    public void insertData(int id, String firstName, String lastName)
    {
        createConnection();
        try
        {
            PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("insert into FRIENDS values(?,?,?)");
            ps.setInt(1, id);
            ps.setString(1, firstName);
            ps.setString(2, lastName);

            int result = ps.executeUpdate();

            if(result>0)
            {
                System.out.println("Data Inserted");
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Something happened");
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally
        {
            closeConnection();
        }
    }


}
```

**DatabaseUI.java**

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class DatabaseUI extends JFrame
{
    private JLabel firstName, id, lastName;
    private JTextField idTxt, firstNameTxt, lastNameTxt;
    private JButton ok;

    public DatabaseUI()
    {
     firstName = new JLabel("First Name: ");
     lastName = new JLabel("Last Name: ");
     id = new JLabel("ID: ");

     firstNameTxt = new JTextField(10);
     lastNameTxt = new JTextField(10);
     idTxt = new JTextField(10);

     ok = new JButton("OK");
     ok.addActionListener(new OKAction());

     JPanel centerPanel = new JPanel();
     centerPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(4,2));
     centerPanel.add(id);
     centerPanel.add(idTxt);
     centerPanel.add(firstName);
     centerPanel.add(firstNameTxt);
     centerPanel.add(lastName);
     centerPanel.add(lastNameTxt);
     centerPanel.add(new JPanel());
     centerPanel.add(ok);

     getContentPane().add(centerPanel,"Center");


     this.pack();
     this.setVisible(true);


    }

    private class OKAction implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
        {
            DataBaseConnector db = new DataBaseConnector();

            int id = Integer.parseInt(idTxt.getText());

            db.insertData(id, firstNameTxt.getText().trim(), lastNameTxt.getText().trim());
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[]args)
    {
        new DatabaseUI();
    }
}
```

But, when I am trying to insert data into the database, it is giving me the following error

```
run:
java.sql.SQLException: Database 'contact' not found.
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory40.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.Util.newEmbedSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.Util.newEmbedSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.Util.generateCsSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.newSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.handleDBNotFound(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection30.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection40.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.jdbc.Driver40.getNewEmbedConnection(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.jdbc.InternalDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.jdbc.AutoloadedDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:579)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:221)
    at DataBaseConnector.createConnection(DataBaseConnector.java:17)
    at DataBaseConnector.insertData(DataBaseConnector.java:40)
    at DatabaseUI$OKAction.actionPerformed(DatabaseUI.java:52)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6504)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6269)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4860)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4686)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2713)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4686)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:707)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:666)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:664)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:680)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:678)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:677)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:211)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:128)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:117)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Database 'contactDB' not found.
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory40.wrapArgsForTransportAcrossDRDA(Unknown Source)
    ... 53 more
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at DataBaseConnector.insertData(DataBaseConnector.java:43)
    at DatabaseUI$OKAction.actionPerformed(DatabaseUI.java:52)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6504)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6269)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4860)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4686)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2713)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4686)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:707)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:666)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:664)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:680)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:678)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:677)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:211)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:128)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:117)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at DataBaseConnector.closeConnection(DataBaseConnector.java:29)
    at DataBaseConnector.insertData(DataBaseConnector.java:65)
    at DatabaseUI$OKAction.actionPerformed(DatabaseUI.java:52)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6504)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6269)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4860)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4686)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2713)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4686)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:707)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:666)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:664)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:680)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:678)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:677)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:211)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:128)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:117)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
```

Please help me. Thanks

Comment: and, I downloaded derby separatly

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The connection URL "jdbc:derby:contact" specifies that the 'contact' database should be found in the current working directory of your process, but that's probably not where it's actually located. When your Java program is run, the current working directory is probably been set somewhere else. You can confirm this by printing out the current working directory at the start of your program.

To get around this for now, you can specify the full path to your database: "jdbc:derby:/path/to/my/db/contact".

If that gets you farther, then you can keep going, but at some point you'll have to think more about where you want your database to be permanently located and how you want to specify that in your program.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly look at your derby/jdbc connection,
This line here:

```
con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby:contact","yohan","xyz");
```

Check if it looks similar to:

```
"jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/contact"
```

Or, as what I've seen, the name of your database is ContactDB... Kindly check...

Thanks...

Comment: yeah, I tried contactDB too. No good at all :(. Anyway, I am going to need embedded driver, that driver is not for embed use isn't it?

Comment: It should work just fine I'm sure... But I guess there is something wrong with your connection string...

Have you considered, using Apache and MySQL?